# Elasticsearch 1.5 vs Elasticsearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I just spent several months building a small search app based on Elasticsearch 1.5 and AngularJS. I know ES 1.5 is old now... but are there major advantages to upgrading to ES 2.0?

Basically what I'm asking is it worth my time to update from ES 1.5 to ES 2.x? If so, how hard is it?

Comment: You can find the whole list of breaking changes [introduced in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.0.html), [2.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.1.html), [2.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.2.html) and [2.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.3.html).

Comment: So you'd need to go through them and see which ones apply to your case or not. If you find out that you're not too impacted, you can upgrade easily, otherwise a bit more efforts might be required.

Comment: @Val, thanks for the links

Comment: @Val, I've been doing some searching on SO pertaining to ES, and it seems that you know quite a bit - you've answered alot of questions on ES. I'm looking to integrate Nutch and ES together - any tips?

Comment: You should ask a new specific question on what you need and add as many details as possible so that people can better help you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of improvements and new features in Elasticsearch 2.X. It is not possible to say which of them will benefit your application, without knowing it better. Checkout this post [Elasticsearch 2.0.0 GA released](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-2-0-0-released)

There are a lot of breaking changes from version 1.X to 2.X. How hard it is to upgrade very much depends on which features you are using and the amount of Elasticsearch specific code you have - take a look at this post: [Key points to be aware of when upgrading from Elasticsearch 1.x to 2.x](https://www.elastic.co/blog/key-point-to-be-aware-of-when-upgrading-from-elasticsearch-1-to-2)

Give it a try :)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain where to start, instead of just down voting the question. Some of us don't have hours to spend googling, searching and reading JUST to get to the starting point